# Is it a good idea to report the index that causes IndexOutOfBound as it?

Tags: python, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

Index to a sequence, such as `list` in Python, `Array` in Java or `std::vector<int>` in C++ can go out of range with negative index in mind. When it happens and the language runtime chooses to detect them, they throw exception with or without the error-causing index. In my situation, I am writing some wrapper code to use an index to access a list, roughly like:

```
function! MyGetItem(list, index)
  return list[index]
endfunction
```

I want to detect the `IndexError` and I have two ways:

- use `try-catch` around the `list[index]` to intersect and probably decorate the built-in error.
- detect the error myself and guard the `list[index]`.

The problem is the built-in error goes wrong when index is negative. For example, if I use `list[-2]`  where `len(list) == 1`, the error will be `index out of range: -1`, which is `index + len(list)` actually. Trying to understand whether it is a general practice to report the index as it, I tried out the same example of several languages. In those not supporting negative index like java and C++, the index is reported as it. In Python however, the index is not reported:

```
>>> s[-1]

IndexError: string index out of range

>>> [][0]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

This makes me wondering whether Python chooses to ignore the bad index is out of some software engineering principle. In my situation, which one should I follow?

Comment: Personally I prefer to report the index as it. It is not hard to detect but carries information that the user probably want to know. If you don't give the index, user has to `print` it himself.

Comment: In this instance, I'm not sure I've ever had the index reported to me from a library I have used. It does happen with strings (like a decoding error) but I'm not sure about lists.

Comment: Ha, and immediately after saying that, I thought of `numpy` and `IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3` was my test. Odd how that fell under my mental radar when I'm reading the error :) Numpy goes with `IndexError: index -5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3` for negative indices.